# What is Macro "Don't Save" command?

Tags: macros

I can use the following command to stop a PDF or any file from opening:

```
OpenAfterExport:=False
```

Does anyone know the command to suppress the `'Don't Save'` prompt?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For excel, there are several ways to 'hide' or 'suppress' the save prompt.

```
ThisWorkBook.Saved = True
```

and

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

will both disable the save prompt from appearing. However, the latter has problems of its own, for example, if you have other issues, I believe those message will also be disabled which could be problematic. After both of these you could add a

```
ActiveWorkBook.Close
```

to close the workbook.

You can do all this in one line with

```
ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
```

If you need to save the workbook, make sure you add a piece of code to autosave before that line of code.

Hope that helps. If that's not what you're looking for, please elaborate and I'll try again.